# Dropdown menu got collapsed after click inside accordion

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using one dropdown menu where inside i used one accordion where each accordion i have anchor tag used. Now when i try to click for expand accordion drop down menu is getting collapsed. Same is happening when click on any item inside accordion.

As far i tried using some observation i was able to manage this issue fix.
I used some condition based on when dropdown get expand based on the event target value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#accordion", function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu.user-menu').show();
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", function(event) {
    if (!$('#accordion').is(event.target) && !$('.list-favorite').is(event.target) && !$('.material-icons.favorite-icon-menu').is(event.target) && !$('.favorite-accordHeader').is(event.target) && !$('.breadcrumb-item').is(event.target)) {
      if (event.target.value == "")
        $('.dropdown-menu.user-menu').show();
      else
        $(".dropdown-menu.user-menu").hide();
    } else if ($('.favorite-accordHeader').is(event.target)) {
      $('.dropdown-menu.user-menu').show();
    }
  });
  
  $('.list-favorite').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu.user-menu').show();
  })
  
  $('.material-icons.favorite-icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu.user-menu').show();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu user-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownUserMenu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="display: block; position: absolute; transform: translate3d(-211px, 44px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
  <div class="bookMarkContainer">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading8">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="favorite-accordHeader" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne8" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne8">
              Product1
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne8" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading8">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <a id="BreadCrumb1" href="#" class="anchorBookMrk" title="Overview" data-link="6129|item1">
              <div class="alert alert-primary alert-no-padding" role="alert" id="8">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</button>
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                  <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">Item1</li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">Item2</li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Item3</li>
                  </ol>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

There are no errors as i am able to manage through multiple condition based on when user click inside then using event.target i used multiple condition to have the dropdown menu expanded. But the question is here Can i able to do the same for little of code instead writing multiple if condition and document click function? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put *event.StopPropagation()* in *onclick* property of accordion and items inside it?
I'm not sure if this is it, because I can't run your snippet.

Comment: I tried this code inside accordion and it's items click but still the dropdown menu is getting closed.

Comment: Can any one suggest here how to handle this type of scenario?